# Does there exist an asymptotic expansion?

Tags: asymptotics

Let  $f(x) = \sqrt x $ and an asymptotic sequence is $\ x^n$ as x goes to zero. Does there exist an asymptotic expansion for f(x)?

Comment: I am searching for f(x)

Comment: For $x\rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly x -- > 0